# Azure App Service using Self-Signed Cert

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I deployed an application out to our app service in Azure, and the app needs to have SSL to run, but since it is still in development I did not want to have to purchase a cert yet, so I created a self-signed cert through openssl.  The private key is 2048 bits, which should be enough, but when I go to apply the cert to the hostname, it just sits there and never applies.

Is there a special step you have to complete to get self signed certs to work, or, are you not allowed to use self signed certs in Azure App Services?

Comment: if you don't run your app of the custom domain, than just add `s` to your url: `https:\\yourwebappname.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: what do you mean by sits there and never applies? Did you manage to create an SSL binding under "SSL certificates" in Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **ServerCertificateValidationCallback** to monitor the verification of server certificate, comparing the certificates between local and server or just returning true.
Now when you invoke the https service in your web app, the verification callback will be invoked automatically. If failed, you will see the errors. If successful, the service response will be returned.

For more details refer this article: http://devchat.live/en/2017/09/29/how-to-invoke-https-service-protected-by-self-signed-certificate-from-azure-app-service/.